# Singular and plural in Maoz Tzur

Tags: chanuka, grammar-dikduk, song-poetry

In the first five paragraphs of *Maoz Tzur*, the first-person singular is used fifteen times. However, the first-person plural is used just once, in ושם תודה **נ**זבח - *and there a thanksgiving-offering **we** will offer*. What is the reason for this discrepancy?

(I'm not considering the last stanza, which twice includes the word לנו - *for us*, as it was written by a different author much later.)

Answer (score 2):

I'd heard it discussed. If I recall correctly, the suggestion was that while the song is generally describing the Jewish people as a collective entity, each person needs to give thanks in their own way.

Comment: Then it should be _todoth nezabeach_.